# Rails 4. ActiveModel timezone converted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.0.1 application. Some reason my query take wrong timezone. I have a below query:

```
puts '=====================', Time.zone.now
@headlines ||= Headline.includes(:admin, :cover).recent.where('published=? AND    publish_at<=?', true, Time.zone.now).limit(4)
```

Output looks like this:

```
=====================
2013-12-02 09:37:44 +0800
  Headline Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" 
  WHERE "contents"."headline" = 't' 
  AND (published='t' 
  AND publish_at<='2013-12-02 01:37:44.941741') 
  ORDER BY "contents"."headline_position" 
  DESC LIMIT 4
```

As you can see my current time is converted in my query. Why?

Comment: See my blog post for info on timezones in rails - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - Datetimes are stored in UTC in the database. Please note these two values are the same 09:37:44 +0800 == 01:37:44

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised check that out... it's pretty short.

basically... you can set your timezone in the `config/application.rb` file, if it's static... and you'll also want to set up an `around_filter` in your `application_controller.rb` to apply the user's machine's timezone before any action is taken (if you have users signing in).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :user_time_zone, if: :current_user

private
  def user_time_zone(&block)
    Time.use_zone(current_user.location, &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: does this work for you in Rails 4.1? I had the same code working in a Rails 3.2 app but it no longer appears to work in Rails 4.1. By not working I mean in my view I can call Time.zone and UTC is returned rather than that set in user_time_zone